# Where are the predefined file templates located for Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, rider

I've just started playing around with JetBrains Rider IDE using one of my existing ASP.NET MVC projects. When attempting to create a new Razor View from template, I've been unable to find any templates which refer to Razor as stated [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference__Templates_Explorer__File_Templates.html). [These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqlNx.png) are all the templates I can see when adding a file template to a chosen folder.

Am I missing something like a plugin, nuget etc...? If worst comes to worst, then I don't mind creating them, it's just a slight annoyance that it clearly states they should be there.

- OS: Windows 10 Build 17134
- JetBrains Rider: 2018.1 Build #RD-181.4379.1191, built on April 14,
  2018

**Update**

I've raised this with JetBrains support and so far they've advised that some predefined templates (Razor being one) are only available in subfolders of Views folder. More info can be found [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-6509#comment=27-2496353). Sadly it's still not working for me but thought I'd add as it may help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug! It's seems to be okay when creating a new solution but then at corrupts the template analytics when updating nugets and/or adding OWIN (I'm guessing the Startup.cs in the root of the project has something to do with it as well).

YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-469774

**Update**

It took nearly 5 years but they finally fixed it. I don't even use that IDE anymore lol!